# Best way to store pixel matrix from camera in real time in python?

Tags: python-3.x, database, image-processing, time-series

Wondering if anyone has any experience saving camera pixel data that is sampling at 1Hz into a database using python?

I want to read the pixel data as a time series for processing, but it quickly becomes and overwhelming amount of data.

I tried using SQL but the database grows too quickly and it no longer functions.

Comment: Usually images are stored on disk using an image format such as PNG, JPG etc.  Lossy formats can help save space if you can cope with some degradation of the image.